# Memory usage/profiling in PHP

Tags: php, memory, profiling

I'm using Netbeans + Xdebug + WinCacheGrind and finally got it to work, but there is no memory usage information. Is it an Xdebug or WinCachegrind limit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP memory profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880458/php-memory-profiling)

Comment: Have a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12483653/653939

Answer (score 0):

I think neither {K,Win}Cachegrind do not handle memory usage, but there still seems to be solutions to view memory_usage in a raw xdebug trace. Example here : http://morefedora.blogspot.com/2008/05/profile-memory-usage-of-php-scripts.html