# php memory management & profiling

Tags: php, memory-management, profiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP memory profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880458/php-memory-profiling)

From what I've found online, all I've seen for tracking memory usage in an PHP application is to use the native "memory_get_usage()" function or buy a commercial product like zend server.

Anybody have some other suggestions? Seems like a good use for Aspect Oriented Programming...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880458/php-memory-profiling

Answer (score 1):

XDebug works great for tracing, profiling, and debugging.

Comment: AFAIK XDebug only does invocation-count and time-based cost profiling, not memory.

Comment: If you look at the trace output options, you can get memory usage per-call as well. I've been using it to optimize my autoload code (which, with a few well-placed caches, brought my page load times down an order of magnitude).