# imagecreatefrompng function giving error of "Out of memory "

Tags: php

I have this information about my servers `php.ini` values set in it.

```
max_execution_time  30
memory_limit    256M
post_max_size   64M
```

When I try to make thumbnail of image its gives me error as follows...

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 27787264) (tried to allocate 15054336 bytes)

in......

image size is 8.81 MB.

This is my code-

```
$sizee = @getimagesize($newfilename);

        switch ($sizee['mime']) {
            case "image/jpeg" :
            $srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($old);
            break;
            case "image/png":
            $srcImage = imagecreatefrompng($old);
            break;
            case "image/gif":
            $srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($old);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: do phpinfo() see if memory_limit displaying correctly ?

Comment: See: [PHP Fatal error: Out of memory...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314733/php-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-80740352-tried-to-allocate-12352-byt) which helps people understand how memory limits come about with GD

Comment: @GBD yes that is what get from phpinfo() function...

Comment: You are you are using 2 different images `$newfilename` and `$old`  ??? What is really happening here

Comment: Its also give same error when your execution is infinite so check your code if you have used any loop like for,while etc in your code then make sure about it.

Comment: More of your code would be better ...

Comment: @Baba,  I am just doing different varible assignment for different use.
`$old = LOCAL_FOLDER . $newfilename;

    $newfilename = LOCAL_FOLDER . $newfilename;`

Comment: @Harry i have just use 1 for loop to fetch the images from db ,nothing else ..  :(

Comment: @user1743213 Ok but I have already faced this problem that I have told you