# How to solve "Fatal error: Out of memory" in wordpress server

Tags: php, wordpress

I got **Fatal error:**

> Out of memory (allocated 31981568) (tried to allocate 32776 bytes) in
>   `/homepages/2/d213994292/htdocs/pub_site/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php`
>   on line 856

How do I solve it?

Comment: see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314733/php-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-80740352-tried-to-allocate-12352-byt, https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-62652416-tried-to-allocate-6571071-bytes

Comment: Actually I didn't found php.ini file in my wordpress folder on server.

Comment: you can add in your file , i think ur trying to upload files rite??

Comment: No i m not uploading file. I want to open my home page. And I got Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 31981568) (tried to allocate 32776 bytes) in /homepages/2/d213994292/htdocs/pub_site/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 856 error

Comment: is ur home page that big that memory allocation is failing??

Comment: ya exactly. what i do to solve these error?  please help me.

Comment: add this in that file and check, `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');`

Comment: I already try this code in my config file. but not working. I host my web on 1 & 1. I think in that some setting is required. but i dont know what i do. so please u have any idea then tell me. thanks

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', "256M");`, this line??

Comment: No i didnt found this line. in which file i add this code??

Comment: add this line in your file and check if ur getting the error.

Comment: I checked it in my config file as well as formatting.php file. but still i got these error.

Comment: if its not there, paste the code, and check if you r getting error.

Comment: I add these code and also check it. but getting same error.

Comment: If any plugin is there to solve these error please tell me.

Comment: im not wordpress developer, im php developer. just change and check once,

Comment: I also increase these value. but not working

Comment: did u try this in `php.ini` file??

Comment: @user3424093 You're answering "I've already tried this" to some comments. Don't you think it would be better if you included what you have already tried in the question? It would help you, help others help you, and help as future reference for other people with the same problem. You can do so if you click on `edit` below your post.

Comment: actually i didnt found php.ini file in my directory. I got php.ini setting in dashboard of 1&1 server. but there have no option to change value only informations are there.

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: It seems surprising that [a method to check if a string is utf-8 or not would end up allocating 30MB](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L842). I think perhaps there's some bad data somewhere in your posts, pages, images or comments that's killing WordPress. If you up the memory limit, do you simply run out of memory at that higher limit? Does this happen on every page? Did this start happening recently? Do you get more information on the problem if you [turn on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Logging)?

Comment: No this is happened in only home page. other pages are working fine. only issue in home page. How to debug ?? please tell me..

Comment: @4EACH I dont know about ssh access because i got only credentials of 1 & 1 login. is there any setting in ssh??

Comment: Thanks to all who is answering me. I got solution in this link.i.e "http://www.designmission.com/1and1-com-hosting/#comments". Actually in that i upload to php.ini file in wp_admin folder which is provided in above link.

Answer (score 1):

Double value of **memory_limit** in php.ini file and then restart apache.

For Example:

```
memory_limit = 512M >>>> memory_limit = 1024M
```

Comment: hey i m working on 1 & 1 server. I m not working in localhost. so please u have any idea then plz help me..its so urgent. plzz

Comment: What you try to do / load ? Can you separate it to smaller processes?