# PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1707606016) (tried to allocate 426680697 bytes)

Tags: php, memory, apache2

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean, it was a 10$ package with 1GB Memory, then I upgraded to 20$ package.

So how it all started was that I'm trying to upload a file from one server to another using cURL parameters, now the issue is... The file doesn't send because I get this beautiful error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1707606016) (tried to allocate 426680697 bytes)
```

Now I have `memory_limit` set to 2048MB because that's how much MB of memory I got on my VPS. Now before I upgraded, I had only 1024MB of memory and the error message was different at the time, and this is what I got.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 530055168) (tried to allocate 529639729 bytes)
```

My VPS has MORE than enough memory to upload a 403MB file, and I have my memory_limit maxed, there's no way I need to upgrade the servers memory limit.

```
memory_limit = 2048M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
post_max_size = 0
max_execution_time = 90000
max_input_time = 90000
```

Obviously it may look like a duplicate, but the solutions on all of the posts I've looked at **don't** work for me. The script that is having its memory_limit is literally a handler that handles the cURL request sent from the alternative server.

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314733/php-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-80740352-tried-to-allocate-12352-byt?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314733/php-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-80740352-tried-to-allocate-12352-byt?rq=1)

Comment: Too bad the solution on that post didn't work either.

Comment: The problem here is that you have 2GB available but 1.7GB is already allocated so there really isn't enough for 426MB more (exceed 2GB)

Comment: How does it take over 2GB to send a file via cURL and use file_put_contents use so much? Especially if the file is 400mb

Comment: Hi can you please post the code you are using to upload the files?. I wonder if its a memory leak kind of issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can changed the php.ini

```
memory_limit = -1
```

and add to httpd.conf And restart Apache

Answer (score 1):

I had  the same issue in a DigitalOcean droplet of 1GB of RAM and 1CPU. 
Trying to install two differents LMS systems, Claroline and Chamilo. **I upgraded the droplet to 2GB of RAM and same CPU.**

The issue was solved. Deffintively it was something related to memmory limits.

Answer (score -1):

You can changed the php.ini

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

and add to httpd.conf
And restart and restart apache