# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 764801024) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Tags: php, linux, apache, memory, memory-management

I have implemented all things as below

[PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1707606016) (tried to allocate 426680697 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179028/php-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-1707606016-tried-to-allocate-4266806)

Implemented all solutions which mentioned in above post

Still it's giving same error

**Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 764801024) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)**

I also tried setting `memory_limit` to `-1` & even in `.htaccess` as well.

Using https://www.digitalocean.com/

Below is the code

```
set_time_limit(0);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$file = file_get_contents("test.csv"); // 50MB File on Server

$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file));
```

It gives error on last line. In CSV file have html tags which i'm removing by Code.

Able to upload same file in my Local. Problem is on Sever. **How to upload 50MB file on Server?**

For now i'm using http://erdconcepts.com/dbtoolbox.html CSVSplitter Which is FREE.

Comment: Increase memory or don't make such memory-hemorrhaging-hugungous variables without releasing previously un-needed references. Or you could chunk out whatever you're parsing.

Comment: HI @Blake Didn't get u clearly. Can you explain in more detail. Thanks

Comment: What part of the comment did you not understand? You didn't provide the code that is erroring out, so it'd all be shots in the dark, or you could follow my previous advice.

Comment: `such memory-hemorrhaging-hugungous variables without releasing previously un-needed references` this part

Comment: you know we cant see you code right?

Comment: Updated question Please check

Comment: well problem is obvious - dont reed 50mb file in to memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: But i need to upload `50MB` file. Commented `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` or removed as well. Still getting issue on Server

Comment: Any updates guys? Please

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` loads the whole file into memory, which leads to the memory issues.

A better approach is to use a stream. Try to process the CSV file this way:

```
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'r');

if ($fp === false) {
    throw new RuntimeException('file not readable');
}

$data = [];

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $row = fgetcsv($fp);
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

This way `fgetcsv` reads only one row at a time and not the whole file.