# Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 11318820 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\file_manager\php\elFinderVolumeFTP.class.php

Tags: memory, xampp, out-of-memory

Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 11318820 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\file_manager\php\elFinderVolumeFTP.class.php on line 640.

Out of memory (allocated 41156608) (tried to allocate 2097233 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\modules\member\data_member.php on line 87

I set momory_limit = 10000M in php.ini. But it still bugs.
(I useing xampp 1.8.2 , PHP / 5.4.16)
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you debug php "Out of Memory" issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114155/how-do-you-debug-php-out-of-memory-issues)