# Laravel Guzzle Return error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using `laravel 5.5.*` and `guzzlehttp/guzzle  ^6.3`. I have created APIs in the same project (`using laravel api.php`) and consuming API on the same project (`using laravel web.php`) and given `throttle 120 per second`.

everything was working properly but suddenly got following error while parsing using guzzle

```
{
    "error": "FatalErrorException",
    "reason": "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 266342400 bytes)",
    "code": 1,
    "trace": []
}
```

Using `XAMPP server`  and `memory_limit=2048M`.
If I access API in the browser it loads fine

Guzzle parsing code below

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => env('API_URL'),
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'],
    'debug' => true,
]);
```

Please, someone, help me how I can fix it? even I cleared cache also generated a new key

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak on your script that always became from redefining a guzzle in a `while loop` , try using `memory_get_usage` to debug the memory usage of your script .

And don't define a class in loops , in your situation that you must use a adapter outside of the loops , like this :

```
$adapter = new \GuzzleHttp\Adapter\Curl\MultiAdapter(
    new \GuzzleHttp\Message\MessageFactory()
);

while (true) {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['adapter' => $adapter]);
    $client->get('http://example.com/guzzle-server');
    echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";
    usleep(20000);
}
```

**EDIT** :
You can debug more on memory eaters :

> [Memprof](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler) is a php extension that helps finding those memory-eaters snippets, specially in object-oriented codes. [[SOURCE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114155/how-do-you-debug-php-out-of-memory-issues)

**EDIT2** :
As the new comments , try to see memory usage via `memory_get_usage` function before & after calling your api .

Comment: i have aded  $client = new Client([
          'base_uri' => $url,
         'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'],
        /*  'headers' => [ 'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',]*/
'debug' => true,

      ]); in trait

Comment: even i have retrieve only one record .will it effect ?

Comment: it maybe not from the one time calling , you can debug it more too , see edited answer

Comment: thanks but for me for calling api one time also giving same error but it was working fine yesterday even i restarted apache and my system no use

Comment: see the `memory_get_usage` before & after calling the api , to check that problem came from the api calling really ?

Comment: ya sure i will check