# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In the same system, I can make call to db, and there is no problem, but in some case ( with the biggest table ), I get

> "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/forge/sximo.sp-marketing.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 311

I debugged the code and the problem is a basic query:

```
"  SELECT partidascapturainfo.* FROM partidascapturainfo    WHERE partidascapturainfo.partidascapturainfoid IS NOT NULL       ORDER BY partidascapturainfoid asc   LIMIT  0 , 10 "
```

When I run the query in a Mysql Client, query runs in 0.17s

I've already set memory_limit to 2048, restart nginx and my query only return 10 rows...

Here are my 10 rows:

```
123044,42016,249,3762,2,,0
123045,42016,249,3761,2,,0
123046,42016,249,3764,1,,0
123047,42016,249,3765,,,0
123048,42016,249,3775,,,0
123049,42016,249,3771,3,,0
123050,42016,249,3772,3,,0
123051,42016,250,3844,HAY,,0
123052,42016,255,3852,,,0
123053,42017,249,3761,1,,0
```

Any Idea what's going on???

Comment: If you show us what kind of data you are retrieving, it could just be that the data in those 10 rows is massive. You might want to profile your code to see where the memory is getting eaten up.

Comment: how can I profile my code? I will update my question with a row as example

Comment: The simplest way is http://stackoverflow.com/a/880483/3358181, but there are more advanced tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

> **Warning:** please be advised that answer below *is not a solution.* One cannot increase the memory limit indefinitely. Another answer is required that helps to *reduce the memory consumption* instead of increasing the memory limit. As a very first measure try to update your Laravel/Eloquent versions, chances that this error is fixed in a newer version.

You can try editing /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:

```
; Old Limit
; memory_limit = 512M

; New Limit
memory_limit = 2048M
```

You may need to restart `nginx`:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

You may also have an infinite loop somewhere. Can you post the code you're calling?

Comment: This sorted me out.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I did it by writing `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` in my main php file of the project. It also worked for me. Thanks @Deciple. Deciple.

Comment: Thank you Deciple and Stefano. This still works on the new version of Php 8.2.4

Answer (score 34):

It is happened to me with laravel 5.1 on php-7 when I was running bunch of unitests.

The solution was - to change memory_limit in php.ini but it should be correct one. So you need one responsible for server, located there:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

so you need a line with

```
 memory_limit
```

After that you need to restart php service

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

to check if it was changed successfully I used command line to run this:

```
 php -i
```

the report contained following line

```
memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M
```

Now test cases are fine.

Comment: I have confirmed an unlimited memory: `memory_limit => -1 => -1`. However I'm still getting errors about out of memory (`Out of memory (allocated 8388608) (tried to allocate 217088 bytes)`).

Comment: I have never suggested setting your PHP to unlimited memory.

Comment: `php -i` displayed `memory_limit => -1 => -1` but in `/etc/php7.1/fpm/php.ini` has `memory_limit=2048M`
Am I missing anything?

Comment: try php -v please

Comment: @Azima Yes, mine too. I change `memory_limit` at `/apache/php.ini` file. In your case, it's `fpm/php.ini`. And then I restart service apache. I don't edit the `php/php.ini` file. It remains `memory_limit=-1`.

Answer (score 10):

Edit the following two files (you may only have one of them):

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini

sudo nano /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
```

Change the memory limit, for example from 512M to 1024M:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Restart nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Check the memory_limit

```
php -i | grep "memory_limit"
```

Run your software to check if the new memory_limit is sufficient.

If not, increase it again (and repeat the steps above). To 2048M, for instance:

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```

Comment: not solve alr tried the error is same but the alert more than smaller Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes)

Answer (score 4):

Share the lines of code executed when you make this request. There might be an error in your code.

Also, you can change the memory limit in your php.ini file via the `memory_limit` setting. Try doubling your memory to 64M. If this doesn't work you can try doubling it again, but I'd bet the problem is in your code.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize there is an accepted answer, and apparently it was either the size of memory chosen or the infinite loop suggestion that solved the issue for the OP.

For me, I added an array to the config file earlier and made some other changes prior to running artisan and getting the out of memory error and no amount of increasing memory helped. What it turned out to be was a missing comma after the array I added to the config file.

I am adding this answer in hopes that it helps someone else figure out what might be causing out of memory error. I am using laravel 5.4 under MAMP.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.

In addition to this answer, I'd suggest analyzing the code properly and figuring out where the error is. 

In my case i was trying to access undefined variables but because it was on the Artisan console it throws such error

Answer (score 4):

For litespeed servers with lsphp*.* package.

Use following command to find out default set memory limit for PHP applications.

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

To locate active php.ini file from CLI

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Example:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/etc/php/7.3/litespeed/php.ini
```

To change php.ini default value to custom:

```
php_memory_limit=1024M #or what ever you want it set to
sed -i 's/memory_limit = .*/memory_limit = '${php_memory_limit}'/' /usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/etc/php/7.3/litespeed/php.ini
```

Dont forget to restart lsws with: `systemctl restart lsws`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you check your Apache server virtual memory in MB and then set the memory limit.

because Server crash problem if your Apache server has 1024 Mb of virtual memory and set 2048 Mb.

> **ini_set use in php code**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

---

Also you can change in **php.ini**:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

---

Find the **path location of php.ini** using the command line in Linux or Windows:

> php --ini

[image: Php ini file location find]

[Change in Php.ini Memory Limit Settings on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution treats the symptom but not the cause. If there's a process that uses fairly more memory than configured there might be something wrong with the process.

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurred to me when using nested try- catch and using the $ex->getPrevious()  function for logging exception .mabye your code has endless loop. So you first need to check the code and increase the size of the memory if necessary

```
 try {
        //get latest product data and latest stock from api
        $latestStocksInfo = Product::getLatestProductWithStockFromApi();
    } catch (\Exception $error) {
        try {
            $latestStocksInfo = Product::getLatestProductWithStockFromDb();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            /*log exception */
            Log::channel('report')->error(['message'=>$ex->getMessage(),'file'=>$ex->getFile(),'line'=>$ex->getLine(),'Previous'=>$ex->getPrevious()]);///------------->>>>>>>> this problem when use 
            Log::channel('report')->error(['message'=>$ex->getMessage(),'file'=>$ex->getFile(),'line'=>$ex->getLine()]);///------------->>>>>>>> this code is ok 
        }
        Log::channel('report')->error(['message'=>$error->getMessage(),'file'=>$error->getFile(),'line'=>$error->getLine()]);

        /***log exception ***/
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check that you are not calling @extends recursively. In my case I had

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

in `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I restored a database and didn't add the user account and privileges back in. Another site gave me an authentication error, so I didn't think to check that, but as soon as I added the user account back everything worked again!

Answer (score 2):

While using Laravel on apache server there is another php.ini

```
 /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

Modify the memory limit value in this file

```
 memory_limit=1024M
```

and restart the apache server

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime limiting your data is also helpful, for example checkout the followings:

```
//This caused error:
print_r($request);

//This resolved issue:
print_r($request->all());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you in the same story as me:

- Laradock or other Docker containers
- No errors
- No logs
- Laravel request eats our all your memory in docker and killed silently
- You even tried to debug your code with xDebug and nothing happened after Exception

The reason is `xDebug 3.0` with `develop` enabled, it prints detailed info about the exceptions and in the case of Laravel take a lot of memory, even 3GB not enough, it dies, without printing any info about it.

Just disable xDebug, at least develop, and it will be fine.

Comment: I am on the same situation with Laradock. How do you disable `xDebug` & `develop`? Could you please give more details? Here is the error from the logs: `production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2621440 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2621440 bytes) at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/ComponentSlot.php:7)
[stacktrace]`

Comment: @Pathros in your `php.ini` or `xdebug.ini` change string `xdebug.mode = develop` to `debug` or `off`

Comment: More info https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

Comment: I have checked the `.env` file and I have it set it to false: `WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG=false` & `PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG=false`. So my memory problem in the `php-worker` container must be something else. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you rebuild your php-fpm container and recreated it?

Answer (score 2):

1. On a Mac, run the following in the terminal

`php -r “echo ini_get(‘memory_limit’).PHP_EOL;”`

This will tell you your current memory limit.

2. Then, run

`php -i | grep php.ini`

This will show you where your php.ini file is.

3. Open this file and increase the memory limit. For example, limitless is:

`memory_limit = -1`

4. Run the first command again to test

`php -r “echo ini_get(‘memory_limit’).PHP_EOL;”`

5. (optional) If it still doesn't work, go to your memory limits file. Mine was

`/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

In here, change the memory_limit

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. No matter how much I was increasing memory_limit (even tried 4GB) I was getting the same error, until I figured out it was because of wrong database credentials setted up in `.env` file

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when trying to resize a CMYK jpeg using the Intervention / gd library. I had to increase the memory_limit.

Answer (score 0):

I had also been through that problem. in my case, I was adding the data to the array and passing the array to the same array which brings the problem of memory limits.
Some of the things you need to consider:

1. Review our code, look if any loop is running infinity.
2. Reduce the unwanted column if you are retrieving the data from the database.
3. Maybe you can increase the memory limits in our XAMPP other any other software you are running.

Answer (score 0):

for `xampp` it there is in  `xampp\php\php.ini`
now mine  new option in it looks  as :

```
;Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
;http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit=2048M
;memory_limit=512M
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experience this same problem today. By referring to answer which states about looping issue, I found that my problem is related to Model has a relationship HasOne that is by default is eager loading in $with. Its keep looping because child getting parent. Then, the parent also has this $with getting the child.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32852252)

Answer (score 0):

The `memory_limit` solution is sort of poor boy approach.
The actual issue is your application booting. So keep removing providers from your `config/app.php` untill the unit test works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is not you code but you configuration.
Try a `composer dump-autoload` so your laravel does not stay looking for old dead files or routes cached before.
You can rise the memmory sky high and it will be reached anyway, so, dump old config and see. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was generated by trying to configure two connections to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a memory size error while using the code I provided, it's possible that you have a large number of records that meet the criteria, and fetching them all at once is causing memory issues. To resolve this, you can paginate the results to retrieve a limited number of records at a time. Here's an updated version of the code with pagination:

```php
$user = Auth::user();

// Define the number of items per page
$perPage = 10;

// Fetch user's own items ordered by id in ascending order with pagination
$his_own_items = Listing::where('user_id', 0)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->paginate($perPage);
    Or
 $all_listing_items = Listing::orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('listing_status', 'Active')->take(10)->get();
```

In this code, I added pagination using the `paginate` or `take` method, which limits the number of records retrieved per page. You can adjust the `$perPage` variable to control the number of items you want to display on each page. This will help prevent memory issues, especially if you have a large number of records that match the criteria.