# Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 174936415 bytes)' in ../src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php:308

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, lamp

I am using AWS Ec2 LAMP server, after setup php.ini memory limit to 256 getting same error, restarted my httpd but no changes.

checked in cmd - `php -i` shows memory_limit = 256M so php.ini is updated then where can i change?

Comment: command line php and webservre php have their own ini files, did you change the right one?

Comment: [Related to this one ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34864524/3282633) ?

Comment: editing /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini: not available in AWS

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen - I seen that answer but not able to edit any cli or fpm of php.ini files, may i know where it is?

Comment: you using xampp or what ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen - LAMP

Comment: @151291 You can also post your own answer and accept it , if you solved it by yourself : )

Answer (score 0):

Based on Error message, your script used all allocated memory (256 * 1024 * 1024 Byte) so your PHP settings is fine, Your script tries to use/allocate more than 256 MB, check your running code

Comment: I changed to 512MB too, same issue.

Comment: Got answer i am trying to write to log files which is return from view files. issue with log of view files. so please delete this answer so that i can delete my question.

Comment: Then check/debug your code, you are doing something like infinite loop which cause this.

Comment: Its not memory issue, I am passing wrong parameter to log files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick. Write this simple code in config file.

If you using main server

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'Your domain name here'){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
}
```

If you using local server

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'Your IP address here'){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
}
```