# PHP artisan "PHP Fatal error" on allowed memory size in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

It's confusing, why this error shown. I'm using `Laravel 5.4`, after using `composer update` then this error shown.

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 495616 bytes) in E:\xampp\htdocs\botble\vendor\symfony\debug\ExceptionHandler.php on line 238
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in E:\xampp\htdocs\botble\vendor\symfony\debug\Exception\FlattenException.php on line 203
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

As some of answer on stack and other community, i'm also test this after update `php.ini` with `memory_limit 2048M`. But still same error shown.

Any suggestion for this issue.

Comment: The error suggests that a 128M memory limit is still in place, I'd investigate as to why your setting isn't applied.

Comment: have you restarted the server using the command "service apache2 restart" or "service nginx restart" ?

Comment: I would not globally increase the memory limit, it is there to prevent rogue or buggy scripts from causing a DoS. Instead increase it just for your one use case, ie: `php -d memory_limit=2048M /path/to/composer update`

Comment: @AdarshSojitra That has nothing to do with it, this is being executed on the CLI which is outside the scope of Apache. And futhermore, Nginx doesn't have a PHP module to reload, it uses a CGI handler (ie, FPM), restarting Nginx has no impact on PHP at all ever.

Comment: Is this vanilla Laravel or you have required other packages? Sharing your `composer.json` might help.

Comment: @josephting This has nothing to do with the issue, it is clear that the memory_limit is still fixed at 128M after the attempt to raise the limit.

Comment: Just found this thread related to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel/34864884

Answer (score 3):

This is memory limit issue .
You can try something like this

Fist find composer directory using bellow command

```
$>which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

After you can update composer with memory limit

```
$>php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

`-1` means unlimited memory

Comment: I used that command but it didn't change my memory limit. php 7.3.18

Answer (score 2):

In my case helped this

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 artisan xxxxxxx
```

Comment: thanks!
works fine, but you need to add the suffix M/G to the 1
`php -d memory_limit=1G artisan xxxxxxx`

Comment: Yes, thank you @BredeBS
Fixed. Add memory_limit=-1