# Allowed memory size of *** bytes exhausted even after adjusting php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, ini

Suddenly this line

```
$data_to_send = @file_get_contents($source);
```

giving me an error

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 353912831 bytes)","file":"/home/forge/biossantibodies.com/app/commands/FileName.php","line":157}}

## upgrade VM resources

I already upgrade my Linode VM to this plan already and still didn't seeing the error.

---

## update PHP.ini

I checked my php.ini, and have updated to

```
cat php.ini | grep _max                                                                                                         
log_errors_max_len = 1024
post_max_size = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
;       setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
```

---

## restart php-fpm service

As you can see, I increase the memory allow to `2000M` already.

I also reboot my php-fpm right  that

`service php5-fpm restart`

---

## phpinfo()

- My changes seem to be reflected.

[image]

[image]

---

## restart entire VM

I even tried to reboot the entire VM.

I still face the same issue, did I change the wrong file?

How do I double check?

Comment: To debug: Add an `echo` that would output the `$source` and filesize just before that line and see what it comes up with.

Comment: Let me do that now, and will update the post.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware : 

I got the size of file is : 
`345620`

Comment: See it here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ml2idhm33mw0x5o/%202018-01-30%20at%208.53.14%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: And is `fire()` only called once? Usually when you run out of memory you're stuck in some kind of loop.

Comment: The script basically loop the entire rows in table of a database, and exported it out to a csv file and SFTP upload it into a SFTP server. Is it loop trhough? yes. As of why it is stuck, I think it is stuck during the upload, but I am not sure.

Comment: The code has been working for 3 years, but now the filesize getting huge, is there anything PHP or Nginx configuration that I should look into  to change ? I have a feeling that code is less suspicious at this point since it used to work.

Comment: I don't know exactly what your code does, but given a file size of 345620 (bytes?) the line generating the error is probably not the exact line where the problem is. I think it has something to do with the code since 536870912 bytes is quite a lot. You could use the next command to check memory usage during execution: http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php again with an echo.

Comment: It may be worth checking whether you have a different `php.ini` file for the command line.

Comment: what commands shold I run ? But I check phpinfo() already.

Answer (score 4):

> "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 353912831 bytes)"

This means you need to also update your php.ini memory_limit directive.

Try put in your php.ini:

```
memory_limit=1024M
```

Comment: Good point, I update mine from 1024M to 4096M. Test it with phpinfo() show correctly, and re-attempt still happening.

Comment: Might be worth checking with the hosting company what your memory limit is with them. If they are limiting you to a certain amount, it wouldn't matter what you changed your php.ini to.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel). You should try restarting nginx/apache.