# Laravel reporting memory size 268MB exhausted but php.ini says 512MB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel job listener is running over 10s of thousands of records, and giving the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1179648 bytes) in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php on line 184


[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                             
 Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1179648 bytes)
```

I have proven using `phpinfo()` that the `memory_limit = 512M`, so I'm at a loss as to what is happening when 512 > 268 :) - also what has `belongsTo` relationship got to do with it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention Laravel job listener which make me assume that you run it through command line. `php.ini` for command line execution may be different than what web server load. Please make sure the `memory_limit` value are same for both `php.ini`. To find where `php.ini` for command line, from shell (assuming Linux), run

```
$ php -i | grep php\.ini
```

Comment: it seems this might be the answer that tricked me - i found command line php.ini at /etc/ , so if I change this I need to just reload php ? Or whole server ?

Comment: oh since its the job listener - i just need to restart the listener for php.ini to take effect?

Comment: AFAIK, `php.ini` will be read everytime you run php through command line. Yes. You need to restart job listener.