# Command 'ui' is not defined in laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authentication

I start a new project in laravel but my composer installed a fresh version of laravel 6.0.1.

`Php artisan make:auth` command can't work.

I try many times but error can't remove

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

installed but
when I use the second command:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

then system show me this message:

```
Command "ui" is not defined.
Using version ^1.0 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 129

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 129

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you deal with the fatal error thrown by your PHP before worrying about laravel UI, lack of memory can create issues for Composer

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 C:\Whatever\Your_project_name>composer require laravel/ui
```

and

```
 C:\Whatever\Your_project_name>php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Just this two inside your project folder.I am using vue but you can try other ones too.

Comment: when i use second command it still says " ui command is not defined" . why? i'm using laravel 7

Comment: Note: You will need to specify a version for laravel ui if you are installing an older version of the framework. For Laravel 6 the command is  composer require laravel/ui "1.*" and I believe laravel 7 is  composer require laravel/ui "2.*"

Answer (score 9):

Did you install the dependency? To run that command you need to install an additional package:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

After this you should be able to run one of these commands:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react
```

In case you need the auth views, you could:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Don't forget to run this after:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed the mentioned package?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur it looks like you have an infinite loop that is using all the memory, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel) to know more about this error and possible solutions.

Comment: not worked, i try maximun  solution but not worked in there, composer install in system but UI not defind

Answer (score 2):

The same error hits me in the new version of Laravel 7.x, What I did the process is really simple: if your composer is old version and the terminal or cmd is giving you warnings to update it using some package then there are chances that the above error hits you.

---

**Solution:**

- **Step 1** : Try the following two commands in your normal terminal not of your project directory. The below command will only update the composer.

  ```
     composer self-update
  ```

  **OR** use the below command (it will update your dependencies plus your composer)

  ```
     composer update
  ```

  When you composer gets updated. check the composer by the below command

  ```
     composer --version
  ```

---

- **Step 2** : First go to your project root folder  C:\Whatever\Your_project_name>

  ```
     composer require laravel/ui
  ```

  Try any of the below command according to your front end framework.

  ```
     php artisan ui vue --auth
     php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
     php artisan ui react --auth
  ```

  At the end don't forget to run

  ```
     npm install
  ```

  If your User Interface is not working properly try below command.

  ```
     npm run production
  ```

---

Answer (score 1):

run "composer require laravel/ui 1" instead of "composer require laravel/ui"

laravel 6 works with version 1.0, it written in docs "Want to get started fast? Install the laravel/ui (1.0)"

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue is laravel 8.0, whenever i tried to run this command

`php artisan ui vue -auth`

after installing the laravel/ui package I was getting the error

> command UI is not defined

I fixed this issue by using this command

```
composer update
```

it automatically install the laravel/ui package into my project and then I run this command to install the required auth for my web app.

```
`php artisan ui vue -auth`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another new project.
You can try this:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.phpcomposer.com
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project2 "7.0.*"
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the version in command line as well:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^1.0" --dev
```

Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-routing) too.

Comment: Please don't post a code only answer without including a textual explanation in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
composer require laravel/ui:*
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue after upgrading from laravel 6 to 8. Installing laravel/ui did not work for me because the package was already installed.

I solved it by manually deleting cache folder at `bootstrap/cache`

Answer (score 0):

I have just started learning laravel and facing the same issue. I have not proper idea about proper way to start learning laravel. So I did the silly mistake.

I have installed composer using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel EMS
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then opened EMS(laravel project's folder) in command prompt. and ran

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

So, I got error ui not defined, My mistake was I ran composer command out of the project folder, and artisan command in project. So I have ran all above command in project's folder and everything is working fine.

I don't know this is correct way to do this or not, but my issue is solved using this method. So, I thought to share with users, if my way is wrong than anyone can also suggest better way.