# How can I allowed more memory for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have just installed Laravel on my web server but after I run the `php artisan serve` command and navigate to my server's Laravel URL I am getting this error:

```
[Tue Oct 15 11:38:54 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77824 bytes) in /Users/apple/eAT/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the memory allocation to PHP by editing the `memory_limit` variable in `php.ini` file.

Alternatively, you can edit the `.htaccess` file and add `php_value memory_limit 256M` to set memory limit for specific application where `256` is the memory allowed to the application. This, however, isn't tested by me.

You may need to restart your PHP server.

Comment: where can I find that file because I am using laravel

Comment: You can find the file in your PHP installation directory in windows. If you are using XAMPP, it should be under `path/to/xampp/php/php.ini`. It really depends upon your environment.

Comment: I am using sqlite

Comment: `sqlite` is the database. What about the webserver? And the OS?

Comment: the web server is localhost

Comment: No, what i meant was that you must have a webserver that would create a server on your localhost. If you are using windows, maybe you installed `XAMPP` to do that or if you are on Ubuntu, then you might have `nginx` or `apache`.

Comment: How did you setup your laravel application? You must have installed PHP right?

Comment: Or if you are still not sure. Open a Shell (CMD if you are using windows) and Just run `php --ini` and look for Loaded Configuration File in output for the location of php.ini used by your CLI