# Review code to prevent allowed memory limit issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

While [this may seem to be the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel) to do, I feel my code is very bad.

I'm running my Laravel 6.x app in a Docker container. When running the code below, I get

> Allowed memory size of ** bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)

No matter how high I set the `memory_limit`, it's the same error (with the new limit). So I want to review my code:

```php
// I'm running a seeder.
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,.....];

// Get all users and update a column:
$users = Users:all();

// Loop and update (we have thousands )
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $index = array_rand($arr);
  $user->someColumn = $arr[$index];
  $user->save();
}
// Another loop for another model with same as above.....
```

This is causing the "allowed memory" issue. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: can you do this in database layer instead? of course you'll exhaust your memory if you iterate each and every user

Comment: What was the `memory_limit` you set? Does your system have enough RAM?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean? Raw SQL? If so, how would I include the random item from the array?

Comment: @Sylar do you really need the seed in PHP layer?, if all can be done in db layer, the better.

Comment: @Kevin Could you show me an example how to include the array, select a random item from the array, should I do it in raw sql? linktoahref's method seems to be going just fine. SQL way seems more advance.

Comment: if your seeder can generate one by one, consider batch update user, may be 100 rows each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fetching all users at once, fetch [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#chunking-results) of users

```
\App\User::chunk(10, function ($users) use ($arr) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $index = array_rand($arr);
        $user->someColumn = $arr[$index];
        $user->save();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and let you know.