# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have `User_controller` and there is function `user_details`, this function returns view name `user_details`.

This view contains number of details, generally there will be 10 to 15 sets(row) of details which display on page(details comes from database using `user_details` table).

It's working fine but in some case when user details goes to 30 to 35 sets(row), i am getting below error in error_log file

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 5896720 bytes) in
> /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php on line
> 63 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
> (tried to allocate 6414336 bytes) in
> /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php on line 1235

Above error return at below line:

```
return view('admin.views.user_details', ['user' => $user[0]
         , 'user_details' => $user_details);
```

Comment: Increase your memory limit in php.ini, ~32mb is rather low value i'd suggest setting at least 128mb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel)

Comment: i don't have server access so i can't modify anything on server, is that any other way like changing in laravel files to reduce memory usage?

Comment: It's recommendable to check _why_ the script takes so much memory. Most of the time, this is unwanted behavior and therefore the script should be changed instead of the memory limit.

Comment: In your UserController, show us the complete `user_details()` method. It looks like you are loading too much data from the database (hint: `$user[0]`) filling memory and crashes in blade rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the memory size anything you need:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');`
```

Before doing anything like this you should check real issue first. Try to prevent it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you need to open < php.ini > file.
find this line :

> memory_limit

then change number beside equal to anything you want. for example:

> memory_limit = 256M

⚠️NOT RECOMANDED⚠️ you can also edit .htaccess file and add/edit this line

> php_value memory_limit 256M

thats all

Answer (score 0):

check memory_limit=-1 in cpanel

[image]

Answer (score -2):

1. Open Cpanel,
2. Check for  MultiPHP INI Editor,
3. then select your website, then check for for memory_limit
4. Set to -1

works for me..thank you

Comment: How this answer is different from the [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005429/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-laravel-8/73002814#68879147)?

Comment: What makes you think that the OP uses cPanel after all?