# Laravel Eloquent cursor() out of memory

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a problem with Laravel's ORM Eloquent cursor() method. Im trying to create some analytics functions for my ecom to get the amount of orders/income and stuff like that, you can check below my code:

```
$fromDate = Carbon::now()->startOfYear()->toDateString();
$tillDate = Carbon::now()->endOfYear()->toDateString();

$orders = Order::cursor()->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $tillDate])->whereIn('status', array(1, 2, 3))->filter(function ($order) { 
  return $order; 
});
$countO = $orders->count();
$sumO = $orders->sum('total');

$orders = VoucherOrder::cursor()->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $tillDate])->where('status', 1)->filter(function ($order) {
  return $order;
});
$countV = $orders->count();
$sumV = $orders->sum('total');

$orders = $countO + $countV;
$income = $sumO + $sumV;

if($orders != 0) {
  $avgOrder = $income / $orders;
}
else {
  $avgOrder = 0;
}

return view('admin.income', compact('orders', 'income', 'avgOrder'));
```

I used cursor() in order to reduce the memory usage since i'm processing large amounts of data but i still get this error:

> Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
> 2338688 bytes)

what am i doing wrong? how can i solve?

Comment: vist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864524/allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce memory usage without editing `php.ini` file, I suggest using `chunk` than `cursor()`.

```
Model::chunk(250, function ($data) {
    foreach ($d as $data) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

This will take less memory but do keep in mind this may consume few seconds more for execution in contrast to `cursor()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a blog post about it. But basically, you need to use unbuffered queries if you don't want to have an out of memory.

Blog post: https://medium.com/@JoseCardona/boost-your-apps-performance-processing-large-mysql-tables-with-eloquent-orm-3724421d97aa

Answer (score -1):

try editing /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:

memory_limit = 2048M
restart nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: any idea on how to solve without increasing memory_limit?

Comment: You can chunk the cache as well if you can't load it all at once.

Do you need all the data to be available at the same time?

That is a lot of records to load into memory at once.

Maybe you can manage to work things out so that you can do what you need to with those records a chunk at a time and remove them from memory when you are done with them.

Comment: the page shows the income and the amount of orders based on a date range, so ye if i select the whole year there are a lot of data to process