# Track memory usage of a method

Tags: php, function, memory, methods

I have yet to find an elegant solution for this. I have a class with a method I want to track the memory usage of without modifying the function:

```
class Example
{
    public function hello($name)
    {
        $something = str_repeat($name, pow(1024, 2));
    }
}

$class = new Example;
$class->hello('a');
```

So the task is, how much memory does `hello()` use without interferring with it?

**Note:** The memory usage of this method should be 1MB. I've tried wrapping the call with `memory_get_usage();` to no avail:

```
class Example
{
    public function hello($name)
    {
        $something = str_repeat($name, pow(1024, 2));
    }
}

$class = new Example;

$s = memory_get_usage();

$class->hello('a');

echo memory_get_usage() - $s;
```

This only results in `144` bytes (Not correct at all). I've tried various magic with Reflection by using the `ReflectionMethod` class.

I have a feeling what I need to do is calculate the difference in the method :(. If someone can think of anything cleaner then you'd really make my day.

**Edit:** I should mention this is in the context of a benchmarking application. So while `memory_get_peak_usage` works in the sense that it correctly returns the memory usage, it will also skew benchmarks ran after  a high memory method. Now if there was a way to reset the memory stats, that could be good also.

Comment: +1 and good luck finding an answer

Comment: What do you need the memory usage for? Just curious.

Comment: I'm trying to fix a bug with a library called CodeBench. http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/3306/selection006p.png and some code: https://github.com/kohana/codebench/blob/3.0.x/classes/kohana/codebench.php#L103

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`register_tick_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) and just dump `memeory_get_usage` out every tick (line) and analysis it later. The class below could be improved by using `debug_backtrace` to find line number related to memory usage or adding time per line using `microtime`.

**Profiler class**

```
class Profiler
{

    private $_data_array = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        register_tick_function( array( $this, "tick" ) );
        declare(ticks = 1);
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        unregister_tick_function( array( $this, "tick" ) );
    }

    function tick()
    {
        $this->_data_array[] = array(
            "memory" => memory_get_usage(),
            "time" => microtime( TRUE ),
            //if you need a backtrace you can uncomment this next line
            //"backtrace" => debug_backtrace( FALSE ),
        );
    }

    function getDataArray()
    {
        return $this->_data_array;
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
class Example
{
    public function hello($name)
    {
        $something = str_repeat($name, pow(1024, 2));
    }
}

$profiler = new Profiler(); //starts logging when created

$class = new Example;
$class->hello('a');

$data_array = $profiler->getDataArray();

unset( $profiler ); //stops logging when __destruct is called

print_r( $data_array );
```

**Output**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [memory] => 638088
            [time] => 1290788749.72
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [memory] => 638896
            [time] => 1290788749.72
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [memory] => 639536
            [time] => 1290788749.72
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [memory] => 640480
            [time] => 1290788749.72
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [memory] => 1689800 // <~ money!
            [time] => 1290788749.72
        )
    [5] => Array (
            [memory] => 641664
            [time] => 1290788749.72
        )
)
```

**Possible Issue**

Since this profiler class stores the data in PHP, the overall memory usage will increase artificially. One way to sidestep this issue would be to write the data out to a file as you go (serialized), and when your done you can read it back.

Comment: With a bit of work, this is good. Thanks for the creative solution, don't think we'll find a better answer :-) Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The [XHProfLive](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=62667953919) profiler developed by the Facebook guys gives this degree of function/method-level profiling, and available as a [PECL download](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).

Answer (score 1):

The memory is released when you are returning from the function.

You might add the `$s = memory_get_usage();
...
echo memory_get_usage() - $s;`
 
block inside of the function. This way, the memory used will not be released.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has already 'freed up' memory after the call to hello() has ended.

What are the results when you do:

```
$s = memory_get_usage();

$class->hello('a');

echo memory_get_peak_usage() - $s;
```

Comment: I've added a comment regarding memory_get_peak_usage(), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a php memory tool.

There is a nice one to be found in this SO thread:
[Tools to visually analyze memory usage of a PHP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255941/tools-to-visually-analyze-memory-usage-of-a-php-app)

[this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880458/php-memory-profiling) holds some further answers regarding your question

Answer (score 0):

The only trustable method I know to achieve this is profiling with tools that are not written in php itself.

Read this:

http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue recently to test that some functions are memory-efficient in Unit tests.

It requires just the Xdebug extension, as it uses Xdebug Profiler under the hood, generating and parsing the same trace files that Kachegrind would. It uses Xdebug functions to programmatically start a Profile on-demand against the function under test, then it parses the trace file, finds the peak memory execution inside that function and return it.

```php
/**
 * Returns the peak memory usage in bytes during the execution of a given function.
 *
 * @param callable $callback A callable to the function to check the memory usage.
 * @param mixed ...$parameters The arguments to the callable function.
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException When Xdebug is not available, or
 *
 * @return int The peak memory usage in bytes that this function consumed during execution.
 */
protected function get_function_memory_usage( callable $callback, ...$parameters ) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'xdebug_stop_trace' ) ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Xdebug is required for this test.');
    }

    $trace_file = xdebug_start_trace( null, XDEBUG_TRACE_COMPUTERIZED );
    call_user_func_array( $callback, $parameters );
    xdebug_stop_trace();

    $trace_file = new SplFileObject( $trace_file );

    $start_context_memory_usage = 0;
    $highest_memory_usage       = 0;

    /*
     * A small Xdebug Tracefile analyser that looks for the highest memory allocation
     * during the execution of the function
     *
     * @link https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/contrib/tracefile-analyser.php
     */
    while ( $trace_file->valid() ) {
        $line = $trace_file->fgets();

        if (
            preg_match( '@^Version: (.*)@', $line, $matches ) ||
            preg_match( '@^File format: (.*)@', $line, $matches ) ||
            preg_match( '@^TRACE.*@', $line, $matches )
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        $trace_entry = explode( "\t", $line );

        if ( count( $trace_entry ) < 5 ) {
            continue;
        }

        $memory = (int) $trace_entry[4];

        if ( $memory > $highest_memory_usage ) {
            $highest_memory_usage = $memory;
        }

        if ( empty( $start_context_memory_usage ) ) {
            $start_context_memory_usage = $memory;
        }
    }

    $memory_used = $highest_memory_usage - $start_context_memory_usage;

    return $memory_used;
}
```

Example results:

```
$function_uses_memory = static function( $mbs ) {
    $a = str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024 * $mbs);
};

$memory_usage_5 = get_function_memory_usage( $function_uses_memory, 5 );
$memory_usage_40 = get_function_memory_usage( $function_uses_memory, 40 );
$memory_usage_62 = get_function_memory_usage( $function_uses_memory, 62 );
$memory_usage_30 = get_function_memory_usage( $function_uses_memory, 30 );

// Result:
(
    [$memory_usage_5]  => 5247000
    [$memory_usage_40] => 41947160
    [$memory_usage_62] => 65015832
    [$memory_usage_30] => 31461400
)
```

Optionally, you can return the memory used and the result, to assert on both, by changing just two lines:

```php
// Store the result after calling the callback
$result = call_user_func_array( $callback, $parameters );

// Return the result along with the memory usage
return [ $result, $memory_used ];
```

This way you can assert the memory usage is expected, while giving the expected result.

If you are going to use this in tests, you can also add this helpful method to the memory trait:

```php
protected function assertMemoryUsedWithinTolerance( $expected, $equal, $tolerance_percentage ) {
    $is_within_tolerance = static function ( $expected, $actual ) use ( $tolerance_percentage ) {
        $upper_limit = $expected + ( ( $expected / 100 ) * $tolerance_percentage );

        return $actual <= $upper_limit;
    };

    $failure_message = static function ( $expected, $actual ) use ( $tolerance_percentage ) {
        return sprintf( 'Failed to assert that a function uses up to %s bytes (%s) of memory (+%s%%). Actual usage: %s bytes (%s).', $expected, size_format( $expected, 4 ), $tolerance_percentage, $actual, size_format( $actual, 4 ) );
    };

    $this->assertTrue( $is_within_tolerance( $expected, $equal ), $failure_message( $expected, $equal ) );
}
```

Example usage:

```
public function test_memory_usage_parsing_long_string() {
    $long_input = str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024); // 1mb string

    [ $result, $memory_used ] = $this->get_function_memory_usage( [$this, 'parse_long_string'], $long_input );

    // If it exceeds 2x the size of the input it should fail. 
    $expected_memory_peak = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2mb

    $this->assertEquals('foo', $result);
    $this->assertMemoryUsedWithinTolerance($expected_memory_peak, $memory_used, 1); // 1% tolerance
}
```

#### Why not `register_ticks_function`?

After I wrote this answer, I also tested the `register_ticks_function` mentioned by another answer to this question, however, I found out it requires `declare(ticks=1)` on the file where the function under test is, and all files where the function under test uses code from, otherwise the tick won't be triggered. The Xdebug approach works without the declare, so it works with all files and tracks memory usage nested deep into the function under test calls.