# How to check which script is consuming maximum memory through Linux Terminal

Tags: php, linux, apache, terminal

Is it possible to check which php script is consuming maximum memory, through linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255941/tools-to-visually-analyze-memory-usage-of-a-php-app   Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

**find out the pid of given process such as firefox:**

```
$ ps aux | grep [f]irefox
```

**Use the cat command or grep command to see /proc/meminfo file:**

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
$ less /proc/meminfo
$ more /proc/meminfo
$ egrep --color 'Mem|Cache|Swap' /proc/meminfo
```

**free command**

**To display free memory size in MB (megabytes):**

```
$ free -m
```